# Make DIV z-index change on click and back to original with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index

I have a certain DIV i want to change the z-index of when being clicked on.
How can i make it a loop, so when unclicked/ clicked again the div goes back to its original z-index.

I already have this JS that changes the z-index, how to complete it so it goes back?

```
$(function(){
  $("#offcanvas-menuright").click(function(){
     $(this).css("z-index", 105);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with help of css

JS:

```
$(function(){
  $("#offcanvas-menuright").click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass("foo");
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
.foo{
z-index:105
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work..
not a possibility to do it with js?

Comment: Is .foo class being added while clickling? Also make sure that z-index:105 is being applied, if not then add z-index:105 !important;